# MERN application mongodb data is now showing

Tags: mongodb, mern

I have deplyed by backend to Render.com and frontend to Netlify.com. In my localhost, it is correctly working, but not working when deployed.
For backend: [Rende.com deplyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgy0i.jpg)

In frontend, nothing is showing. In navbar, when click product, there will be a list of products from Mongodb but showing nothing. There are some errors showing in the console. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxQe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to add more useful details.
Your port seems off ( 10000 ), make it 80 or 443.
Try hitting health api directly.
From frontend logs, it is not able to connect to backend, port is the reason for that i guess.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have solved the problem now. Various problems were there.